# How would you recommend I automate website data entry?

Tags: javascript, json, cron, web-scripting

I'm looking for a simple script that I can use to automate website data entry.

Trigged when the value of a cell in a gsheet changes, the script will login to the website, navigate to the correct url, fill one or two fields to select the correct item to update, click a link, enter the updated data value and confirm the update is successful - or report an error - and then log out of the website.

It should handle multiple cells changing at the same time.

This is not a critical application, so regularly polling the gsheet is also viable.

I'm not a coding expert, so suggestions for how to achieve this are most welcome.